# Keras: What is model.inputs in VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I start playing with keras and vgg16 recently, and I am using keras.applications.vgg16.

But here I come with a question about what is `model.inputs` because I saw others using it in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py although it does not initialize it

```
    ...
    input_img = model.input
    ...
    layer_output = layer_dict[layer_name].output
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, filter_index, :, :])
    else:
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

    # we compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
    grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]
```

I checked the keras site but it only said that is an input tensor with shape (1,224,224,3) But I still don't understand what is that exactly. Is that an image from ImageNet?Or a default image provided by keras for keras model?

I am sorry if I don't have enough understanding of deep learning, but can someone explain it to me please. Thanks

Comment: These are dimensions of your image. A shape of (1,224,224,3) means you have 1 image (I might be wrong on this one), with both height and width of 224 pixels, and 3 channels (RGB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 4 dimensions of `(1,224,224,3)` are the `batch_size`, `image_width`, `image_height` and `image_channels` respectively. `(1,224,224,3)` means that the `VGG16` model accepts a batch size of `1` (one image at a time) of shape `224x224` and three channels (RGB).

For more information on what a `batch` and therefore a `batch size` is, you can check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) Cross Validated question.

Returning to `VGG16`, the input of the architecture is `(1, 224, 224, 3)`. What does this mean? That in order to input a image into the network, you will need to:

1. Preprocess it to reach a shape of (224, 224) and 3 channels (RGB)
2. Convert this to an actual matrix of shape (224, 224, 3)
3. Group together various images in a batch of the size that requires the network (in this case, the batch size is 1, but you need to add a dimension to the matrix, in order to obtain the (1, 224, 224, 3)

After doing this, you can input the image to the model.

Keras offers few utilitary functions to do these tasks. Below I present a modified version of the code snippet shown in *Extract features with VGG16* from [Usage examples for image classification models](https://keras.io/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models) in the documentation.

In order to have it actually working, you need a `jpg` of any size named `elephant.jpg`. You can obtain it running this bash command:

```
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Zoorashia_elephant.jpg -O elephant.jpg
```

I will split the code in the image preprocesing and the model prediction for clarity:

### Load the image

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
```

You can add prints along the way to see what's going on, but here is a brief summary:

1. `image.load_img()` load a PIL image, already in RGB and already reshaping it to (224, 224)
2. `image.img_to_array()` is translating this image into a matrix of shape (224, 224, 3). If you access, x[0, 0, 0] you will get the red component of the first pixels as a number between 0 and 255
3. `np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)` is adding the first dimension. x after is has shape `(1, 224, 224, 3)`
4. `preprocess_input` is doing an extra preprocessing required for imagenet-trained architectures. From its docstring (run `help(preprocess_input)`) you can see that it:

   > will convert the images from RGB to BGR, then will zero-center each color channel with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling

This seems to be the standard input for ImageNet training set.

That's it for the preprocessing, now you can just input the image in the pretrained model and get a prediction

### Predict

```
y_hat = base_model.predict(x)
print(y_hat.shape) # res.shape (1, 1000)
```

`y_hat` contains the probabilities for each of the 1000 imagenet classes the model assigned to this image.

In order to obtain the class names and a readable output, keras provided an utility function too:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
decode_predictions(y_hat)
```

Outputs, for the `Zoorashia_elephant.jpg` image I downloaded before:

```
[[('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.48041093),
  ('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.47474155),
  ('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.03912963),
  ('n02437312', 'Arabian_camel', 0.0038948185),
  ('n01704323', 'triceratops', 0.00062475674)]]
```

Which seems pretty good!

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make the question clear enough. I am looking at the code from https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py. It visualizes some filters, but it uses model.inputs to get a gradient:
     grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]   
      But it does not initialize the model input, therefore I am confused is there any default input of keras VGG16 model

Comment: Hi @cwl6. I think this is a pretty different question from the previous one and my answer addressed the previous one extensively. You can always open a new question and the community will be glad to help!. Regarding this question, you can see on line `91` that it's actually initalizing a random noise image with the line `input_img_data = np.random.random((1, 3, img_width, img_height))`., with shape `(1, 224, 224, 3)`,  which fits my explanation.  This input is plugged to the model in line `98` using the definition of `iterate` done in `84`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know it takes your times to answer my question. But in line 78 , it used the model input to create a function. Anyway I will open another new question. Thanks

Comment: `input_img` is a placeholder for the `model.input`. This is "plugged" to `input_img_data` using `iterate` on line `84`, where `iterate` is a [K.function](https://keras.io/backend/#backend-functions) which maps inputs (`input_img_data`) to outputs (the model gradients and losses). The connection between `input_img_data` and `input_img` happens there, saying to iterate to take `input_img_data` as input to obtain the gradients and losses of the model, it's implicitly saying to plug the `input_img_data` to `input_img` and, in turn, to `model.inputs`. I'm not super confident with k

Comment: Now, I'm already researching :P ... I'm pretty noob with Keras too. The idea is the following: basically, you are just defining the structure of the model with `model.input` as the input until you execute a line saying: "ok, this is the input". This line is line `98`. This line (`loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])`) says: compute `loss` and `grads` running the model defined before with `input_imag_data` as the input. `iterate` is the connection between both.

Comment: Combining line `98` and `84` you can see that it's actually running `loss_value, grads_value = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])([input_img_data])`, a use of the [functional api](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).